# Name error: name 'pynative' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

Am getting below error after running code using python2.7.18.

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pynative' is not defined
```

Code :

```
import string
def removechars(stri1,num):
    if num < len(stri1):
        new_string = stri1[num:]
        print(new_string)
    else:
        print('Cannot remove characters from the string')
string1 = input('Enter a string ')
print('the entered string is ',string1)
num1 = int(input('Enter the number of characters you want to remove from earlier string'))
print('The new string is ')
removechars(string1,num1)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Is this the full traceback for the error?

Comment: I just ran your code in my interpreter and it worked fine.  Is there more to your code than what is displayed?

Comment: @Prateek Dewan, This is the full error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new1.py", line 8, in <module>
    string1 = input('Enter a string ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pynative' is not defined

Comment: @Daniel Walker, that is the full code i have, and i ran in windows powershell. Do i need to install any packages for python2.7 strings.

Comment: Thank you @Prateek Dewan . <br/> This code is running successfully in python3.x